# How to copy spreadsheet's sheet into another spreadsheet without creating a new sheet copy when using google sheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

1.I have 2 spreadsheets. let's call them  A and B.

2.A has a sheet,let's call it X while B also has a sheet,let's call it Y.

3.X has every information that I want to copy into Y,such as values,formats,pictures(that I put into the cell)

4.Because X has the pics in it.So I cant use importrange to get the pics shows in Y since they were in different spread,so I have to copy it into Y using script.

5.My goal is just copy X into Y without create other sheet in B.

5.At first，I am using code like this

```
function CopySheet() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("A's ID");       //Get spread A
    var cs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //Get spread B

    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("X's name");  //Get sheet X
    sourceSheet.copyTo(cs);                           //Copy X into B (create a new sheet Z)
 }
```

Although the newly created sheet Z can shows the pics, but in Spread B I have other sheet that use formulas that keeps refs with Y.If I delete Y and rename Z to Y.I found that every formula's refs are lost!

So is there has some way with the scripits that can only copy X into currently existed Y without create new sheet?

Comment: I think the answer is that you have to copy X in A to B and then use copyTo to move ranges from X (copy) in B to y and when your done you can delete X (copy) in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

NOTE:*This solution is brought to you by @Cooper who suggested the possible answer in a comment of this question. This answer is posted as a community wiki.*

To achieve what you aim, this is what worked for me:

1. Copy your sheet `X` from `A` to `B`
2. Copy all the content from `Copy of X` in `B` to `Y`
3. Delete `Copy of X`

The following code is an example of how this would work. You can find explanations to it in the comments of the code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // get spreadsheets A and B
  var a = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID SHEET A');
  var b = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID SHEET B');
  
  // copy sheet X into spreadhseet B
  a.getSheetByName('X').copyTo(b);
  
  // copy the values of the cells in the sheet just created in spreadsheet B
  var range = b.getSheetByName('Copy of X').getRange(b.getSheetByName('Copy of X').getLastRow(), b.getSheetByName('Copy of X').getLastColumn());
  
  // paste all the content of the sheet X into Y (into the desired range of Y)
  range.copyTo(b.getSheetByName('Y').getRange('A1'));
  
  // delete the sheet that was created when passing the information from one spreadsheet to another
  b.deleteSheet(b.getSheetByName('Copy of X'));
  
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thanks Randwolf ! Your opinion is very helpful.But I found the line                                      
var range = b.getSheetByName('Copy of X').getRange(b.getSheetByName('Copy of X').getLastRow(), b.getSheetByName('Copy of X').getLastColumn());  that only returns 1 cell.So I use getDataRange  instead and it works perferct for me,Thank you very much!